# Did Dumbledore control the sequence of events in which took place in Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

I don't mean actually control them but did he know what would happened and did he plan the causing actions behind them?

Comment: Related: [How was Harry supposed to defeat Voldemort in Dumbledore's original plan?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25286/how-was-harry-supposed-to-defeat-voldemort-in-dumbledores-original-plan)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He did not know for sure what would happen but he had, in his words, some guesses and he clearly planned for things:

- He suspected Ron would possibly need to return to the Trio so he left him Deluminator
- He knew Harry would be torn between Hallows and Horcruxes, and depended on Hermione to help him slow down his impatience (thus giving her the book and not telling Harry about the Hallows)
- He knew Harry would need help facing Voldemort in the end and left him the Stone.
- He knew Death Eaters would control the school and made sure Snape would be in the position to protect the students (via his sacrifice)
- He knew Harry would destroy the Horcruxes and let Voldemort kill him, thus destroying the last soul fragment
- He knew Harry would need the sword and thus arranged for Snape to deliver it

etc....

We see a lot of that in both Snape's memory when Harry views it in the Pensieve once Snape died, and from conversation in "King's Cross" (aka Harry's head) between Harry and Dumbledore.

Comment: And the reason for downvote is???

Comment: Upvoted to cancel it; nice answer!